# Find the inductance using function generator, oscilloscope, capacitors, resistors, multimeter, voltage generator

Tags: inductor, oscilloscope, inductance

I am trying to find the inductance of a inductor. I have tried many different methods such as putting the inductor in parallel with a capacitor to form a tank circuit and in series with a resistor with 1% tolerance.

The specific sites I used are:

wikihow.com/Measure-Inductance

youtube.com/watch?v=GF4AbbBGa5M

===============================

Problems I encountered with links
1) The oscilloscope I use outputs voltage/div. I do not have a current probe.

2) When I run a sine wave, or any wave form, from the function generator. The waveform I see on the oscillator is the same wave I used from the function generator; Same frequency.

3) No option to adjust current output from function generator.

4) My oscilloscope outputs a normal sine wave. I don't see a decreasing/increasing sine wave.

5) I know that the readings are wrong because when I switch capacitors, the math shows that the inductance has changed. I have a fixed inductor that I used to test also.

=============================

Other stuff to mention:

The oscilloscope I am using

pd.infn.it/elettronica/Strumenti/Immagini/MSO4104.JPG

The function generator I am using

tek.com/sites/tek.com/files/media/image/AFG3000C-Arbitrary-Function-Generator-Datasheet--346462-1-L.jpg

Comment: Well, if you apply a sine wave to a linear circuit, you will see that same sine wave (perhaps with different phase and amplitude) anywhere in the circuit. This is a universal property. To answer your other questions, a circuit is needed.

Answer (score 3):

1 you do not need a current probe. Put an ohmic resistor in series with inductor and measure the voltage over the resistor

2 capacitor and inductor do not change an input sine wave, only the amplitude and phase

3 not much to say

4 where are you putting your oscilloscope probe? Put a series resistor with your inductor and try to read over the inductor. If the sine keeps the same, maybe your inductor has a low inductance. Try to lower the frequency of the sine generator

Comment: Thanks for the respond. I will give this a try. Also, what do you mean by tension?

Comment: Sorry, I mean voltage

Comment: Please edit your answer.